# ReactJS Fetch Called Once But Multiple Requests Go Out

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

This is a re-write of a previous post I made since I am able to reproduce the same problem using much simpler example.

I've created a simple app using npx create-react-app. I added logging logic to my App.js file as follows.

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  console.log("###? App()");

  const logStuff = () => {
    console.log("###? Logging stuff")
    fetch("https://httpbin.org/post", {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({error: "hello", message: "there"}),
    })
      .then(() => console.log('###? useLog() response'))
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('###? Failed to send log with error: ' + error);
      });
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {logStuff()}
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo"/>
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

When I launch the app I get the following logs:

```
###? App() App.js:5
###? Logging stuff App.js:8
###? useLog() response App.js:9
###? useLog() response
```

In the network tab I see the following:
[image]

The App() function is called once. The logStuff() function is called once; but in the network console I can see two requests go out to that URL and I don't understand why.

Comment: React is free to re-render your components (and call the hooks) as many times as it feels like, you are not guaranteed to not re-render. Put in a conditional check to avoid extra requests. Also, in general you should put side effects in a `useEffect` hook.

Comment: How are you using this function? like useLog()("error","message")?

Comment: In the component I bring it in by const log = useLog(); then I use it as log.error('error', 'error-description);

Comment: Interestingly you are not using any hooks. You need to keep your error object in the state with useState hook and as @JaredSmith mentioned, you need to use useEffect with the error state as a dependency. Your API call will happen inside the useEffect hook. If that's not the concept, share the code where you are calling the useLog(), after all, it's just a function.

Comment: @SanishJoseph OP is using `useContext`.

Comment: Oh yeah. Missed that.

Comment: I also don't quite understand how useEffect() would help here. The problem isn't that I'm calling fetch() 2 times. It is only getting called once based on the logging I'm getting. The problem is that two requests go out per one call to fetch.

Comment: Would conditionally fetching based on existence of `logInContext.accessToken` help?

Comment: it's hard to tell without seeing the code where the hook is called and sometimes you can't trust the browser's `console.log`. The first thing that comes to mind is that the error function is called twice somewhere, maybe because the function is not memoized, try to wrap it in a `useCallback` hook with `logInContext.accessToken` as a dependency

Comment: I'm guessing you want to render some JSX based on the response you receive. But, what you're doing is not the right approach. Usually, if you want to make a fetch call from within a component *once*, you put it inside a `useEffect` hook. Once the response is available you store it in a state (created using the `useState` hook). Your rendering logic needs to look at this state variable and update accordingly. TL;DR You need to read more about [React hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've put logStuff function in your return statement, which is why you're experiencing this behaviour. Remember as a good practice return statement of a component should only return JSX/Components and should not be used for any calls.
If you're running a function inside return statement, it should return JSX/Component.

This is the right way.

```
import './App.css';

function App() {
  console.log("###? App()");

  useEffect(() => {
     logStuff() //this should be regular practice for side effects
  },[]) //useEffect would run once only. If you want to change it on condition then provide other arguments to the array.

  const logStuff = () => {
    console.log("###? Logging stuff")
    fetch("https://httpbin.org/post", {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({error: "hello", message: "there"}),
    })
      .then(() => console.log('###? useLog() response'))
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('###? Failed to send log with error: ' + error);
      });
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      // {logStuff()} this was the problem, the function was calling on each render
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo"/>
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```